# Does a php folder management script exist?

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, exists

Basically, I want to upload about 10,000 family photos that have been organized into folders according to names of the people involved. What I'm looking for is php driven software that allows me to put passwords on each of the folders initially and then allow the family members themselves to manage their folder by adding additional username/passwords that they can add and remove.

I know php so I can make this if need be but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel. Also, if this can be done via script + htaccess that would be fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that [PHP Photo Gallery](http://phpgraphy.sourceforge.net/) will do what you want, and if it doesn't, it shouldn't need much tweaking.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds pretty specific, and you would probably have to write it yourself. Also, google is your friend. If you have any questions while you are writing the software, feel free to ask here again!